# Spaces of Graphs with Fixed Number of Edges and Verticies

Tags: graph-theory

Let $V$ be a set of verticies, considered as fixed, and let $X$ be the set of all directed graphs $(V,E)$ where $E$ is a set of edges defined on $V$.  Can $X$ be identified with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ (or set of matrices), for some large enough $d$?

Comment: If $|V|>|\Bbb{R}|$ then there are more such graphs than points in $\Bbb{R}^d$ for any finite number $d$, so no. On the other hand the answer is yes for $d=|X|$. What sort of identification are you looking for?

Comment: Oh, I'm looking for finite graphs (thanks for the point on rigour, I appreciate it) and any reasonably/commonly used identification with some matrices (most likely).

Comment: You can alway map a graph to its adjacency matrix, yielding $d=|V|^2$.

Comment: What about the laplacian matrix?  I've heard this term being used but not sure hwat for?

Comment: That works too; the two are very simply related.

Comment: Is there an advantage of the latter?  Sorry if this question is abit vague

Comment: No. Though 'advantage' really depends on what you want. But computing one from the other is a trivial matter. It's barely worth distinguishing between the two when characterising matrices.

Comment: Right.  Let me try one last one.  If $V$ is fixed and finite, then is the map taking $E$ to the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of normalized eigenvectors of the graph Laplacian injective?

Comment: If you don't restrict to simple graphs, then this is not injective.

Comment: That's fine... If you have a reference (so I can readup abit) on this fact, I'd accept this as an answer.

Comment: I'm not claiming that it *is* injective on simple graphs; I have no idea and no references.

Comment: On second thought it seems unlikely to be injective; the unit vector $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector of the Laplacian of any graph. It is also not clear how your map is defined; there are at least two unit eigenvectors for each eigenvalue, and infinitely many if an eigenvalue has higher multiplicity. What's wrong with just mapping to the Laplacian or adjacency matrix?

Comment: I'm just curious.  Thanks for the help!